# Dynamically assign property to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays

```
var arr1 = [
   {id: 1, name:'Rick'}, 
   {id: 2, name:'Daryl'}, 
   {id: 3, name:'Carl'}, 
   {id: 4, name:'Negan'}
];

var arr2 = ['Colt', 'Crossbow', 'Glock', 'Bat'];
```

I want to assign items from `arr2` to the `arr1` so the final result would be something like this

```
arr1 = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Rick', weapon: 'Colt'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Daryl', weapon: 'Crossbow'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Carl', weapon: 'Glock'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Negan', weapon: 'Bat'}
];
```

What is the best approach to achieve this? Any suggestion/example will be appreciated!

Comment: A simple loop would do the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.forEach` with a value and an index to modify `arr1`:

```js
arr2.forEach((v, i) => arr1[i].weapon = v);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't like `forEach` you can use `map` and spread

```js
var arr1 = [
   {id: 1, name:'Rick'}, 
   {id: 2, name:'Daryl'}, 
   {id: 3, name:'Carl'}, 
   {id: 4, name:'Negan'}
];

var arr2 = ['Colt', 'Crossbow', 'Glock', 'Bat'];

result = arr1.map((pr, index) => ({...pr, weapon: arr2[index]}))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr1 = [
 {id: 1, name:'Rick'}, 
 {id: 2, name:'Daryl'}, 
 {id: 3, name:'Carl'}, 
 {id: 4, name:'Negan'}
];

var arr2 = ['Colt', 'Crossbow', 'Glock', 'Bat'];


arr2.forEach((value, index) => {
 arr1[index].weapon = value
  // OR 
 arr1[index]['weapon'] = value 
 // OR
Object.defineProperty(arr1[index], "weapon", { 
                      value: value,
                      writable : true,
                      enumerable : true,
                      configurable : true });
})
```